# How do i create a program that tells the user which number is greater than the other

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to create a program that tells the user which number is greater than the other in C#
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy5jF.png)

Comment: You are not assigning the user input to the variables. Please put your code in the question as text instead of linking to a screen shot.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please include code, error messages, and other _text-based_ information ***as text***, [not as screenshot](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You can open visual studio and create new project as you like but you can select c# console app then when project loaded you notice that there exist main method in this method you can write logics you want it according to your question you can do it easily it is basics of c#

```
     Console.Write("Input first number)
        int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Input second number)
        int num2= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if(num1>num2) Console.Write("num1 is greater than num2: "); else  if(num2>num1) Console.Write("num2 is greater than num1: "); else  if(num1==num2) Console.Write("num1 is equal num2: "); else  Console.Write("invalid numbers: ");
```

Comment: What happens if the user enters a non number or nothing at all?

Comment: last condition will occure and you can try it and show us result